# How to add an image in my database table

Tags: mysql, image-uploading

I got a table with columns but i'm trying to update the 'img' column to a specific image.

This is what I tried :

```
UPDATE employees
SET img="(LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Test/Desktop/Test.png')"
WHERE wname='Foo';
```

Sadly enough the picture doesn't get converted to a real image.

Comment: Do you want to store the image as data in database,or simply the image's path ?

Comment: you have to use BLOB variable type to insert image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using LOAD_FILE in wrong manner, Try this :

```
 UPDATE employees
 SET img=LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Test/Desktop/Test.png')
 WHERE wname='Foo';
```

See detail : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

Answer (score 0):

In you query you are just setting the value of img as 
"(LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Test/Desktop/Test.png')" because of the double coats.
So instead of file being uploaded path location is being inserted
"(LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Test/Desktop/Test.png')"

@Sagar Joon is absolutely right you have do the way he is saying.